# HTML JS returns error 'cannot set value of null'

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys I'm trying to to use `innerHTML` but it always returns null error. I followed some help in the forum to load the JS part after the html. I tried to use `onload` method still it is failing. But the variable does hold the value when I tried to use alert. Here is a sample code I'm using.

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innnerHTML' of null

```html
<div id="displayfacts"></div>
<div class="slideshow">
    <img id="i1" src="p1.jpg">
    <img id="i2" src="p2.jpg">
    <img id="i3" src="p3.jpg">
    <img id="i4" src="p4.jpg">
</div>
```

```js
var islid=1;

var notices = new Array (       
    "The Vikings",       
    "Wolves",
    "Turn",
    "Smell");

window.onload = function slider() {
    document.getElementById("#displayfacts").innnerHTML = notices[islid];
    $(".slideshow #i"+islid+",#displayfacts").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".slideshow #i"+islid+",#displayfacts").delay(3000);
    $(".slideshow #i"+islid+",#displayfacts").fadeOut(2000);
    (islid<5)?islid++:islid=1;
    setTimeout(slider, 6000);
}
```

Comment: can you show the html? Do you have a html element with an `id` of `displayfacts`?

Comment: share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Open a debugging window. Place a breakpoint on the `document.getElementById` line. Type the expression `document.getElement.ById("#displayfacts")` into the console to see its value.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. I made two mistakes as pointed out by others.

Spelling for innerHTML was wrong and should use ("displayfacts") instead of (#displayfacts) in getElementById

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the id of an element with the CSS (and jQuery) selector for an element by its id. If you have this element:

```
<div id="displayfacts">...</div>
```

then its id is just "displayfacts", not "#displayfacts", so you'd want to use `document.getElementById('displayfacts');` in your code (note there's no #).

You're currently trying to get a reference to an element with the id `#displayfacts` (i.e. `<div id="#displayfacts">...</div>`), which returns null (because there's no matching element) and therefore gives you the error when you try to set the innerHTML property.

Comment: That must be the silliest mistake I have made. Thank you pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

If we can't see your HTML is hard to help, but checking the js, it seems that when you call getElementById you are using "#displayfacts" when it should be "displayfacts".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Also if you are using jquery why you are using getElementById?

Comment: "Also if you are using jquery why you are using getElementById?" Why not? jQuery will just call that method anyway, so you're saving yourself the creation of a jQuery object and an additional method call that just achieves exactly the same thing.

Comment: Good point, @AnthonyGrist, it just seems that the use of jquery and vainilla js made him confuse to call the id with "#"

Answer (score 1):

i**nnn**erHTML - correctly is innerHTML with 2 n's.

Try this :

```
var innerHTML =  "";
if(notices[islid] != null)
{
   innerHTML = notices[islid];
}
document.getElementById("#displayfacts").innerHTML = innerHTML;
```

Comment: OMG thank you. And I'm really really sorry for this. Ill be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

two issues in your code

change

```
document.getElementById("#displayfacts").innnerHTML = notices[islid];
```

to (remove `#` since id is `displayfacts` not `#displayfacts`)

```
document.getElementById("displayfacts").innnerHTML = notices[islid];
```

also change

```
(islid<5)?islid++:islid=1;
```

to

```
(islid<3)?islid++:islid=0; //since your array has only 4 elements
```

Final code

```
var islid=0;

var notices = [  "The Vikings", "Wolves", "Turn", "Smell"];

window.onload = function slider() {
    $("#displayfacts").html( notices[islid] );//why not use jquery only
    $(".slideshow #i"+islid+",#displayfacts").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".slideshow #i"+islid+",#displayfacts").delay(3000);
    $(".slideshow #i"+islid+",#displayfacts").fadeOut(2000);
    (islid<3)?islid++:islid=0;
    setTimeout(slider, 6000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. There is more to the code than I posted. I only posted a sample. But even then the innerHTML part alone doesnt show up. I'll post a jsfiddle if I can. And jquery's .html didnt work either.

Comment: @Sammy `And jquery's .html disnt work either` sorry that was a bug, please check again

Comment: I was using .html() as an assignment that was the problem. Sorry I'm just starting out in jQuery. Will study more on the syntax. Thanks for your time.